# Making a call to .NET 3.5 library using sharepoint from .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have a web application using .NET 4.5 (let's say P4) calling a .NET 3.5 library (let's say P3) that uses the Sharepoint 2010 libraries.

=> P4 references P3 that references Sharepoint libs.

In the P3 app.config:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>-->
  </startup>
```

I can call P3 methods from P4 BUT when it reaches a Sharepoint function like this:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("https://browser-working-url"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("We are here");
}
```

...it crashes saying: *"Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.42000 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime."*

**Is there a way to force P3 to use the 3.5 framework or do you see any workaround to make SP function calls work?**

Must: keep P4 using at least .NET 4.5

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do that I am aware of.  SharePoint is going to see the calling function is using .NET 4 base.  It doesn't support that.  About the only thing you could do is create your SharePoint functionality into a web service that you can call from your .NET application.  I believe this should work.  I know you can call a .NET 4+ web service from SP2010, and I believe it works the other way too.

Not 100% sure though I will admit.